# Force google image search

Tags: php, html, image, google-custom-search

I have a simple site where the top content is a navigation tab with two navigation lists: Web and Image. Under the navigation tab i have a google custom search search element/bar. The web tab is by default selected to web.

By default the google custom search will search for the web, is there any way i can force it to search for images by php or optionally javascript. So when the images tab is set in the navigation menu it will search the google images instead the web ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can basically create your own Google Image search form. The most important thing to know is that the URL for image search looks like:

```
http://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=Glee
```

(Where "Glee" is your search term).

Here's a simple example of how the form would be, HTML:

```
<h1>Google Image Search</h1>
<input type = "text" id = "srchterm"/>
<button type = "button" onclick = "reDirect();">Search!</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function reDirect() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=' + document.getElementById('srchterm').value;
}
```

Hope that helped you in any manner!

Comment: I am using the google custom search: http://www.google.no/cse/ When Searching with the google custom search u will get redirected to even google.com/something or your own domain with search results and your id for your search engine will not being passed if you this or am i wrong ?

Comment: @user1449761 Yes, I understand that. You can use the same method above to search only within your site by adding this to the beginning of your query: `site:yoursite.com `. Google Custom Search API does **not** have a method to specify that the search should be image-only.

Comment: @user1449761 My point is that unfortunately you can't use the same Google CSE interface you use for Web search in your site for image search.

Comment: Ok, but the search element will search not mine site but the google image search. Is it the same for this ? Something i can do in xml ? Thanks for help

Comment: @user1449761 It's the same. Here's the result of putting together the code in my answer above: [Link](http://pastehtml.com/view/c8jyl2jcl.html).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this url:

http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=queen

Answer (score 0):

I hope this text can be useful is to reach 30 words

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia Google</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method=get action="http://www.images.google.com/images">
        <input type="search" name="q" >
        <br>
        <button type="submit">------</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```